# C# How to get strings between two characters? C sharp

Tags: c#

I want to do get strings between two characters. I want to write to different text boxes these strings. How can I do? Thanks.

eg:
XXX001:111111:DH8D:N0491:RPLL:F370:JOM DCT LIMLE DCT:.....

```
Display;
txtbox1=111111
txtbox2=DH8D
txtbox3=N0491
.
.
.
txtbox6=JOM DCT LIMLE DCT
```

Comment: start with [`string.Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split), which gives you an array of strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the string by using the inbuilt str.split() function.
This function will give you an array that you can use to fill the information in textboxes.

ex:

```
string phrase = "XXX001:111111:DH8D:N0491:RPLL:F370:JOM DCT LIMLE DCT:";
string[] words = phrase.Split(':');
//Use array words to fill your textboxes.
```

Comment: This was the solution I was looking for. Thank you very much.